# Wrong First Argument Type

Tags: java, android

This is a sample of my imports

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

And this is where i use the Fragment

```
private void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpager) {
    /*Creating a tab adapter*/
    TabAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment1(),"Activity");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment2(),"Friends");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment3(),"Inbox");

    /*Set the adapter to the view pager property*/
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I get an error of Wrong First Argument found Fragment1 Required Fragment2

Here is the Adapter Class
And i am not sure where the problem is
in the code
  below
        private class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
    private ArrayList<Fragment> Fragments;
    ArrayList<String> FragmentNames;

    /*Constructor*/
    TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        Fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        FragmentNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /*Helper method which adds a fragment which in turn adds a tab*/
    void AddFragment(Fragment1 fragment, String name) {
        Fragments.add(fragment);
        FragmentNames.add(name);
    }

    /*Get the current item of the tab its on*/
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Fragments.get(position);
    }

    /*Returns the number of fragments that are in this adapter*/
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Fragments.size();//Check on This
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return FragmentNames.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual error message, might help to see a bit ore information.

Comment: Is it for your AddFragment call? How is that method declared?

Comment: please give the code for TapAdapter

Comment: @algrid that's the code. I only get a red line under the addFragment method saying Wrong first Argument

Comment: @algrid come see how i implemented it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddFragment() is expecting **Fragment1** as the first parameter. So the error is obvious.

```
/*Helper method which adds a fragment which in turn adds a tab*/
void AddFragment(Fragment1 fragment, String name) {
    Fragments.add(fragment);
    FragmentNames.add(name);
}
```

If you want to make your method accept multiple classes, then you have two options.

1. Make `AddFragment()` accept `Fragment` as the first parameter

   `addFragment(Fragment fragment, String name)`
2. Declare an interface and make your classes comply to that interface, and use the interface as the Parameter.

#### FragmentInterface.java

```
public interface FragmentInterface{
    // You can declare common functionalities here
}
```

#### Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements FragmentInterface {
    // Class implementation
}
```

#### TabAdapter.java

```
/*Helper method which adds a fragment which in turn adds a tab*/
void AddFragment(FragmentInterface fragment, String name) {
    Fragments.add(fragment);
    FragmentNames.add(name);
}
```